# Chart control remove label arrows

Tags: c#, charts

When the rotation angle is zero then everything looks good, but when I rotate it starting from 60 degrees, label arrows appear, how can I remove the label arrow? thanks!

How the labels should look when rotated 90 degrees
[image: How the labels should look when rotated 90 degrees]

The arrows I was referring to I want to remove
[image: The arrows I was referring to I want to remove]

Comment: Which charting library is this, and what platform are you targeting?

Comment: The standard 'Chart' Control under Data section in toolbox. I'm using .Net 4 and winforms.

Comment: ASP.NET, WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use SmartLabels you can control the Caps like this:

```
chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineAnchorCapStyle = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
```